# Ignition causing problems with Electrics?? Ford Focus 06

Tags: electrical, ford, troubleshooting, ignition, computer

Really hoping someone can help as taken to a mechanics and they keep charging me $$ although they cant find the fault!

My computer system in 2006 Ford Focus doesn't work sometimes ( usually at the most inappropriate time ) so no indicators , wipers the hazards wont work .. everything really. I have found that I have to pull over and re start the car turning the key half way and then fully on usually fixes it but sometimes this doesn't work.

I have noticed that the problems usually occur when the headlights are on and so in the daylight its usually fine.

Has anyone experienced similar?

Are there any troubleshooting/remediation steps that someone can recommend to me?

How can I nail down the source of the issue?

I feel like this car will be the death of me.

Thank you very much in advance.
Chloe

Comment: I start with checking the connections to the battery, clean them up, make sure the connections are tight, replace if needed.  Check your main ground wire and its connection to the body.  make sure it is clean and solid.

Comment: Sounds like a possible faulty ignition switch to me.

Comment: what do you mean by everything? the switches on the column? or other body electrics like the radio etc...